# Updating StatefulSets in Kubernetes with a propietary vendor?

Tags: kubernetes

I could not be understanding Kubernetes correctly but our application relies on a proprietary closed-source vendor that in turn relies on Solr. I've read articles on rolling updates with StatefulSets but they seem to be dependent on the application being aware and accounting for new schema versions, which we have no ability to do without decompiling and jumping through a lot of hoops. Let me describe what we're trying to do:

WebService Version 1 needs to be upgraded to WebService Version 2, this upgrade is none of our code and just the vendor code our code relies on. Think of it like updating the OS.

However WebService Version 1 relies on Solr Version 1. The managed schema is different and there are breaking changes between Solr Version 1 and 2. Both the Solr version and schemas are different. If WebService Version 1 hits Solr Version 2 it won't work, or worse run break Solr Version 2. The same is true in reverse, if we update WebService Version 2 and it gets Solr Version 1 it will break that.

The only thing I can think of is to get Kubernetes to basically spin up a pod for each version and not bring down 1 until 2 is up for both WebService and Solr.

This seems not right, am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a problem Kubernetes can solve. First work out how you would do it by hand, then you can start working out how to automate it. If zero-downtime is a requirement, the best thing I can imagine is launching the new Solr cluster separately rather than doing an in-place upgrade, then launch the new app separately pointing at the new Solr. But you will need to work out how to sync data between the two Solr clusters in real time during the upgrade. But again, Kubernetes neither helps nor hinders here, the problems are not in launching or managing the containers, it's a logistical issue in your architecture.

Comment: I thought the same thing, and that was my approach until I read this "Thus, it doesn’t matter which StatefulSet (or Deployment) the pods come from so long as a pod’s labels match the service’s selector. This means we can deploy multiple StatefulSets in the cluster, each pointing at different versions of Solr, and the service happily routes traffic to both.

We’ll leave it as an exercise for the reader to deploy another StatefulSet with a single replica using a different Solr version." https://lucidworks.com/post/running-solr-on-kubernetes-part-1/

Comment: That is okay if you're just changing versions, the hard part in your case is that the schema is also not compatible in either direction. There is a reason that is generally avoided in apps in general :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what the [canary release strategy with Solr](https://lucidworks.com/post/running-solr-on-kubernetes-part-1/) suggests is simply having a new StatefulSet with the same labels as the one with the previous version.

Since [labels can be assigned to many objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors) and network-level, services route requests based on these, what will happen is that requests will be redirected to both StatefulSets, emulating the canary release model.

Following this logic, you can have a `v1 StatefulSet` with, say, *8* replicas and another `v2 StatefulSet` with *2*. So, ~80% of requests should hit `v1` and ~20% `v2` (not actually, just to illustrate).

From there, you can play with the number of replicas of each `StatefulSet` until you "roll out" 100% of replicas of `v2`, with no downtime.

Now, this can work in your scenario if you label each duo (application + Solr version) in aforementioned way.

Each duo would receive an ~N% of requests, depending on the number of replicas it has. You can slowly decrease the number of replicas of `*duo* v1` and increase the next updated version.

This approach has the downside of using more resources as you will be running two versions of your full application stack. However, there is no downtime when upgrading the whole stack and you can control the percentage of "roll out".